# How to inject a map of key-value pairs into an Object with just Core Java?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

How can I inject a map into an object using only Core Java?

I have a map with 4 key-value(String, Object) pairs and a class with 3 fields, I want to invoke the setter method based on the key name and set them.

```
{
 "variableA": "A",
 "variableB": true,
 "variableC": 1,
 "variableD": "DONT USE"
}

public Class Example {
  public void setVaraibleA(String variableA);
  public void setVaraibleB(Boolean variableB);
  public void setVaraibleC(Integer variableC);
}

Example example = new Example();
// Do something to map it
assert(example.getVariableA.equals("A"));
assert(example.getVariableB.equals(true));
assert(example.getVariableC.equals(1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to @BeppeC's answer, if you can't easily determine the type of the object that you're injecting at runtime, and assuming that you don't have duplicate property names, I would use [Class's `getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) method and [Method's `getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getName--) method.

Basically, I would write some code like the following:

```
Method[] exampleMethods = Example.class.getMethods();
Map<String, Method> setterMethodsByPropertyName = new HashMap<>(exampleMethods.length);
for (Method exampleMethod : exampleMethods) {
  String methodName = exampleMethod.getName();
  if (!methodName.startsWith("set")) {
    continue;
  }
  // substring starting right after "set"
  String variableName = methodName.substring(3);
  // use lowercase here because:
  // 1. JSON property starts with lower case but setter name after "set" starts with upper case
  // 2. property names should all be different so no name conflict (assumption)
  String lcVariableNmae = variableName.toLowerCase();
  setterMethodsByPropertyName.put(lcVariableName, exampleMethod);
}

// later in the code, and assuming that your JSON map is accessible via a Java Map
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()) {
  String propertyName = entry.getKey();
  String lcPropertyName = propertyName.toLowerCase();
  if(!setterMethodsByPropertyName.containsKey(lcPropertyName)) {
    // do something for this error condition where the property setter can't be found
  }
  Object propertyValue = entry.getValue();
  Method setter = setterMethodsByPropertyName.get(lcPropertyName);
  setter.invoke(myExampleInstance, propertyValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Java Reflection to get a method (given its name) and invoke it with a given parameter.

```
Example example = new Example();
Method method = Example.class.getMethod("setVariableA", String.class);

method.invoke(example, "parameter-value1");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! That solves part of my problem. Is there a way that I can 1. Automatically create Method object for all the setter method without hard coding the field name? 2. By knowing the key name "variable-a", automatically use variableAMethod.invoke(example, "variable-a-value")?

Comment: Sure, I think you can just build the method name i.e. 

`String methodName = "set" + map.getKey()`